# Is there any general algorithm of finding multiples of a given number in a given range?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Is there any way of finding multiples of a given number , say `p` , in the range (x , y) {exclusive of x and y}

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975539/how-do-you-find-the-number-of-multiples-of-a-given-range-of-numbers) . But the answers only address the example given by the OP and not as general algorithm.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/975792/112944 reads like an answer to me if you substitute $x$, $y$ and $p$ in their appropriate places.

Comment: Note that multiples of same number form an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple solution: Let's assume $p$ is a natural number.

The first multiple of $p$ in $(x,y)$ will be $p \cdot (\lfloor x/p \rfloor + 1)$ and the last multiple will be $p \cdot (\lceil y/p \rceil - 1)$, where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ stands for "round upwards" and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ stands for "round downards".

Comment: So I suppose $(\frac{p_ {last} - p_{first}}{p}) $/p will give me the required answer right?

Comment: Check it on an example - there is an off-by-one error in there. In fact, try out these formulas on several examples, both to see if they are correct and to understand why they work.

Comment: @JohannesKloos , Wait .Thats interesting. I wrote a script and that error factor is not an error factor but a required part of the answer. I have tested it on lots of cases and always $\frac{p_{last} - p_{first}}{p} + 1 $ is the answer. From where is the +1 coming from ?

Comment: @NeoNØVÅ7 If you have a range of natural numbers from $a$ to $b$ (inclusive), that range will include $b-a+1$ numbers. This can be understood by seeing that $b-a$ counts all numbers $\le b$, but not $\le a$ - it does not count the start point.

Comment: One more question,. Rather than using $p \cdot (\lfloor x/p \rfloor + 1)$ ,  I think we can also use $p \cdot (\lceil x/p \rceil)$ . Can we? Or will there be any edge cases?

Comment: There will be an edge case if $p$ divides $x$ in this case - try it out!

Comment: @JohannesKloos , Oh I see. In that case , the multiples will be inclusive of x.